# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: \twitter-api-php-master\TwitterAPIExchange.php:321

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I am developing a custom wp plugin that deals with twitter so I am using this as repository https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

This is my code for the shortcode:

```
function ct_twitter_shortcode_func( $atts ){    
    ob_start();
    include_once '/includes/twitter-api-php-master/TwitterAPIExchange.php';

    $ct_twitter_keys = get_option("ct_twitter_keys");
    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => $ct_twitter_keys["OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN"],
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => $ct_twitter_keys["OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"],
        'consumer_key' => $ct_twitter_keys["CONSUMER_KEY"],
        'consumer_secret' => $ct_twitter_keys["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
    );

//echo dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem';
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$getfield = '?screen_name=bikegearup&count=20';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest(true, array(CURLOPT_CAINFO => '/includes/twitter-api-php-master/cacert.pem'));

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'ct_twitter', 'ct_twitter_shortcode_func' );
```

but I got this kind of error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /includes/twitter-api-php-master/cacert.pem CApath: none' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pluto\wp-content\plugins\ct-socials\shortcodes\ct-twitter\includes\twitter-api-php-master\TwitterAPIExchange.php:321 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pluto\wp-content\plugins\ct-socials\shortcodes\ct-twitter\class-fw-shortcode-ct-twitter.php(23): TwitterAPIExchange->performRequest(true, Array) #1 [internal function]: ct_twitter_shortcode_func(Array, '', 'ct_twitter') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\pluto\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(345): call_user_func('ct_twitter_shor...', Array, '', 'ct_twitter') #3 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\pluto\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(223): preg_replace_callback('/\[(\[?)(ct_soc...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[ct_twitter sty...') #5 [internal function]: do_shortcode('[ct_twitter sty...') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\pluto\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(298): call_user_func_array('do_shortcode', Arra in C:\xampp\htdocs\pluto\wp-content\plugins\ct-socials\shortcodes\ct-twitter\includes\twitter-api-php-master\TwitterAPIExchange.php on line 321

I also tried to include https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem but still it won't work.. can anyone help me with this?

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance...

Comment: Just an idea but try absolute path as it may be not php search path like for includes or requires that CURLOPT_CAINFO requires. It may supposed to be system path which '/' wold be root dir, not current working directory.

Comment: I tried this ` ->performRequest(true, array(CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem'));` but still won't work...

Comment: Is it correct path though? If your current working directory isn't `includes/twitter-api-php-master/` then it seems like it will be incorrect, try to echo it for debug purposes. (Edit: I mean if __FILE__ is not where cacert.pem is)

Comment: I get it now.. thakns.. the issue is the location of the file .. thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help